# Python 2.7 error: 'set' object has no attribute '__GETITEM__' after having raw_input conditions

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, error-handling

error after input from user, always tells me that set object has no attribute. I have looked at other questions but have not had any success in my scenario. I have tried a lot of things. Basically the program has a cipher that I created and I want to replace characters from the user into to the cipher alphabet I have. I have replaced the translations for confidential purposes by the way. Hope someone could please help me out with this.

```
cache_list  = {
'result'
}

usr = raw_input("Usr: ")



if 'a' in usr:
result1 = usr.replace('a', "hash1" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result1)


if 'b' in usr:
    result2 = usr.replace('b', "hash2" , 1000000000)
    cache_list['result'].append(result2)

if 'c' in usr:
cache_list['result3'] = usr.replace('c', "hash3" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result3)


if 'd' in usr:
result4 = usr.replace('d', "hash4" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append('result4'
                                )


if 'e' in usr:
result5 = usr.replace('e', "hash5" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result5)


if 'f' in usr:
result6 = usr.replace('f', "hash6" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result6)

if 'g' in usr:
result7 = usr.replace('g', "hash7" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result7)


if 'h' in usr:
result8 = usr.replace('h', "hash8" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result8)


if 'i' in usr:
result9 = usr.replace('i', "hash10" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result9)


if 'j' in usr:
result10 = usr.replace('j', "hash11" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result10)


if 'k' in usr:
result11 = usr.replace('k', "hash12" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result11)


if 'l' in usr:
result12 = usr.replace('l', "hash13" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result12)


if 'm' in usr:
result13 = usr.replace('m', "hash14" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result13)


if 'n' in usr:
result14 = usr.replace('n', "hash15" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result14)


if 'o' in usr:
result15 = usr.replace('o', "hash17" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result15)


if 'p' in usr:
result16 = usr.replace('p', "hash18" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result16)



if 'q' in usr:
result17 = usr.replace('q', "hash19" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result17)


if 'r' in usr:
result18 = usr.replace('r', "hash20" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result18)



if 's' in usr:
result19 = usr.replace('s', "hash21" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result19)




if 't' in usr:
result20 = usr.replace('t', "hash22" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result20)




if 'u' in usr:
result21 = usr.replace('u',"hash23" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result21)



if 'v' in usr:
result22 = usr.replace('v',"hash24" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result22)



if 'w' in usr:
result23 = usr.replace('w',"hash26" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result23)




if 'x' in usr:
result24 = usr.replace('x',"hash27" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result24)





if 'y' in usr:
result25 = usr.replace('y',"hash28" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result25)





if 'z' in usr:
    result26 = usr.replace('z',"hash29" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result26)





if ' ' in usr:
result27 = usr.replace(' ', "space" , 1000000000)
cache_list['result'].append(result27)



print cache_list[result]
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What behavior are you seeing and what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 2):

You (probably accidentally) created a set instead of a dictionary when initializing your `cache_list` variable. Try using:

```
cache_list = {"result": ""}
```

This will create one key `result` in the dictionary, and set its value to be `""` (the empty string).

Here is a console example:

```
>>> cache_list = {"result"}
>>> type(cache_list)
<type 'set'>
```

This set doesn't have a `__GETITEM__` function as the interpreter complained. But using my suggested initialization will get the correct type:

```
>>> cache_list = {"result": ""}
>>> type(cache_list)
<type 'dict'>
>>> cache_list["result"]
''
```

Summary: `{"result"}` creates a **set**, but `{"result": ""}` creates a **dict**.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to store in a list, the cache_list should be this way:

```
cache_list = {"result": []}

usr = raw_input("Usr: ")

if 'a' in usr:
    result1 = usr.replace('a', "hash1", 1000000000)
    print result1
    cache_list['result'].append(result1)

if 'b' in usr:
    result2 = usr.replace('b', "hash2", 1000000000)
    cache_list['result'].append(result2)

print cache_list["result"]
```